# How do I match an element and any and all attributes it contains?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my sample XML.

```
<root>
  <para indent="yes">First paragraph</para>
  <para indent="no">Second paragraph</para>
  <para indent="yes" level="1">Third paragraph</para>
  <para indent="no" level="2">`Fourth paragraph</para>
</root>
```

In altova, I can match all  tags (using `//para`), which gives me the result:

```
para First paragraph 
para Second paragraph
para Third paragraph
para Fourth paragraph
```

Or I can match all attributes of para ( using `//para/@*`  ), which gives me the result:

```
indent yes
indent no
indent yes
level 1
indent no
level 2
```

But I want to combine these xpaths and get the following desired result:

```
para Paragraph 1
indent yes
para Paragraph 2
indent no
para Paragraph 3
indent yes
level 1
para Paragraph 4
indent no
level 2
```

Is there an xpath that will give me this result in altova or oxygen?

Comment: Not sure if you realize this, but the elements you retrieve with `//para` contain the attributes (as well as any child attributes).

Comment: In Altova, the child attributes are only displayed if the element has no direct child text node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use union between the two selectors:

```
//para|//para/@*
```

Working example: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=Ag